# two projects and two pojos and same database in java

Tags: java, hibernate

I have 2 projects 1is webapplication and another is standalone application.
both are using the hibernate on the same DB.
My Problem is

I am unable to keep it properly still i try.
I just want to access the method in the project2 from project1.So I made the jar and iam using p2.jar in project1.created the session in the p1 and calling the p2 but the pojos available there is same and still i am getting the cast exception in java.

Ex:in P1 iam invoking the m1() of P2.

in P1 method the logic is like this

creating session;

```
session.beginTransaction();
Query preChkQuery=session.createQuery("from X x ");

orcId=((X)orList.get(0)).getId();

//invoking p2 method

P2class p2class = new P2class ();
p2class.execute(orcId)

And in method execute
session.beginTransaction();
Query preChkQuery=session.createQuery("from X x ");
we=((X)orList.get(0)).getId();
return we;
```

And the problem starts here once the call enters into the p2 method and starts executing it gives class cast exception

Comment: if I understood correctly you have 2 identical POJOs one in P1 and onother one in P2, am I right? If I'm right, this should be avoided since it can generate some classloading issues like the classcast exception you are having

Comment: yes,class loading with different package in p2.jar and different in p1 project.when i kept both the pojos with different packages in hibernate.cfg.xml it gives exception .so only one pojo is configured in the hibernate.cfg.xml.but when the call happens it starts loading the hibernate.cfg.xml that is located in the p2.jar is loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the design has a fundamental flaw. If I understood it properly, You are packaging the `p2.jar` in `p1`. Which means that all the classes are available in p1 war at all the times. I am not sure if you added the p2.jar in deployment assembly of p1 while running.

I have a similar setup as follows:

A `common.jar` which contains all the `Hibernate models` and the `SessionFactory` configuration. It is MVC application so I have the `DAO` layer in `common.jar` as well.

I have the `ServiceImpl` in war and I invoke the `DAO.method()` which manipulates the entity and it works fine.

Can you check your deployment assembly?

Comment: Yes its right,but common.jar is just a hibernate application.Contains all the classes (POJO,DAO,Service,hibernate configuration files).i.e., using main class works fine. but When used it as the jar file in the P1 project gives class cast exception.......

Comment: More over i observed the session contains same pojos defined even while accessing the p2.jar classes.

As dharam said while deployment i have the hibernate.cfg.xml file both in the web application and also in the jar file .But the cfg file get used only when  the p2.jar DAO used.

Pojo classes in P1 project is same as in P2.jar

Please help me out struggling a lot 
in simple words unable to access standalone classes(POJO) using Webapplication POJOs

Comment: Why do you want the POJOs in p1??? This is wrong, if both domain classes are same then you can reuse the classes from p2.jar

Comment: actually iam using p2.jar as code reuse developed for some other functionality.Before using this p2.jar,lot of development happened and for the new requirement we need to use this jar.but as i already informed p2.jar is a standalone application wchich is working fine for particular requirement.To fullfill the same requirement i need to reuse the exixting code means just call the same class to finish of the job.Thanks for the quick and regular reply.Hope u help me fixing the issue.

Comment: now i have removed all pojo's from p1 project and kept in p2.jar and its working fine.. thank you for your suggesstion

Comment: Glad to hear that. Now your design is better and improved.